# How to make ticks equidistant in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the plot shown below:

[image: photo]

Now the problem is that I need to make the fonts large at the same time, I need to make them clear (disjoint). I do not care about the ratio of spaces between ticks. one solution is to have the spaces equidistant so that I can read the tick labels carefully. Any Idea how i can do that?

---

Following Yoda's comments I surely do get a better look.
I do not know how to get the aspect ratio but I use the following code

```
    figure('Units', 'pixels', ...
    'Position', [100 100 500 375]);
```

The font size is 16 and I set the Axis as:

```
    axis([-1 1 0 100])
```

[image: photo]

Comment: What `fontsize` are you using? Could you post the output of `get(gca,'fontsize')`?

Comment: @alandalusi: One possibility is to rotate the labels using the [XTICKLABEL_ROTATE](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabelrotate) function from the File Exchange.

Comment: @yoda: I also have it bold. But even if it was not bold I would still have the same problem:  set( gca,'FontName'   , 'Helvetica','FontWeight','bold' );

Comment: @alandalusi: That is indeed what I used in the plots below. You can perhaps try reducing it to 14 or 15... You could also give Amro's suggestion a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more helpful if you also told us what the aspect ratio is and what font-size you're using. If I try to reproduce it, I get a reasonable looking plot where the labels are easy to read at a fontsize of 16 or 18.

[image]

Now, moving the tick marks around or intentionally labeling in a different position can lead to lot more problems in interpretation (for one, the data point will no longer align with the tick) and I wouldn't suggest that approach. In your case however, is `0.33` equivalent to `1/3`? If so, you could use `1/2` and `1/3` and save some space. You can set it with

```
set(gca,'xtick',[-1,-0.5,-0.33,0,0.33,0.5,1],...
    'xticklabel',{'-1','-1/2','-1/3','0','1/3','1/2','1'},
```

and it should look like this:

[image]